# Inner header image dont change

Tags: css

Header inner image doesnt change,example when u edit a page in the bottom is header image i upload it but the image doesnt change
[LINK](http://zastradeschool.com/rreth-nesh)

Code for inner header image

```
.inner-page-banner {
background: url(images/inner-page/1.jpg) no-repeat center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
z-index: 9;
```

Here is the background image url(images/inner-page/1.jpg), i want a pic for every page but i cannot change it.
[setting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHjnx.png)

Comment: I see image in `.inner-page-banner`. So maybe check Network tab in DevTools to see if it's loaded correctly.

Comment: Yes. i want to change this image i upload it in page settings but still deosnt change .. i will upload an setting image

Comment: You want to change the picture to a different one?

Comment: If you're using a administrative tool to change your header image you will need to provide us the code that queries this. Your CSS alone will not be sufficient for us to locate the issue. Anywho, why don't you just change the `background-image` path rather than using that tool.

Comment: Yes. i want to have different images in every page, i know i can change it from url..   but then i have the same image for all pages.

Comment: Then set it in the HTML next to your `inner-page-banner` div for each page and disable the image path in your CSS. (e.g commenting it out)

Comment: how to set it in the html ? can u explain a little

Answer (score 0):

If you want a different header image for each page you can set a different image path manually after your `inner-page-banner` div in HTML or create classes in CSS which has a `background-image` property which you then apply the class to the div in HTML.

### Setting background in HTML only:

In your HTML file locate the `inner-page-banner` div. 
Add `background-image` attribute with the image path like this:

```
<div class="inner-page-banner" style="background-image: url('/path/of/your/image.png')"; >
    // content
</div>
```

### Setting background with use of CSS:

Alternatively you can do this in CSS by creating image classes which sets the background image and you only have to define this class in the header div.

**CSS:**

```
.image1 {
    background-image: url('/path/of/your/image1.png') no-repeat center;
}
.image2 {
    background-image: url('/path/of/your/image2.png') no-repeat center;
}
```

And refer to one of the image classes for the div in the HTML file.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="inner-page-banner image1"; >
    // content
</div>
```

**Note:** You would need to remove the background property in the CSS where `inner-page-banner` class is if you do not wish to use that image anymore and proceed to use either of these methods instead.

Comment: Okay thank u, i will try can i add it in CUSTOM CSS or ?

Comment: First option would be to just change it in your HTML file.
Second option (which is somewhat cleaner) takes the use of both CSS and HTML.

Comment: Okay. how to edit the html in wordpress? do i have to download the file and then edit it ?

Comment: @Charlie Go to **Appearance → Editor** in your WordPress dashboard and choose the child theme you have activated.
There are **index.php**, **functions.php**, **header.php**, **footer.php** etc.

Comment: I dont have child theme. i only have this activated theme ?

Answer (score 0):

Please mention full path here like

background: url(http://yoursitename/images/inner-page/1.jpg) no-repeat center;